# Trigonometric Functions Involving Calculus

Tags: calculus

Find $$\int \sin x\cos x \;dx.$$

I have no idea how to do this. Can someone please show me how. FYI this is not a homework question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the identity $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$.
So
$$\int \sin x\cos x \;dx=\int \frac{\sin2x}{2}dx=-\frac{1}{4}\cos2x+C$$

Comment: Can you pleas elaborate what you did between the second and last step? thanks

Comment: Use the substitution $u=2x$. Think you can take it from here?

Comment: Or you use $(\frac{-\cos 2x}{2})' = \sin 2x$

Answer (score 2):

This is a straightforward $u$-substitution: let $u=\sin x$, so that $du=\cos x\,dx$. Then

$$\int\sin x\cos x\,dx=\int u\,du=\frac12u^2+C=\frac12\sin^2x+C\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

Without substitution, directly using that

$$\int f'(x)f(x)^ndx=\frac{f(x)^{n+1}}{n+1}+C\;,\;\;-1\ne n\in\Bbb R$$

for any differentiable function $\,f(x)\;$ , and then

$$\int \sin x\cos x\,dx=\begin{cases}\int \sin x (\sin x)'dx&=\frac{\sin^2x}2+C\\{}\\-\int (\cos x)'\cos x\,dx&=-\frac{\cos^2x}2+C\end{cases}$$

Now, both ways above are correct, but: can you explain why the results are "different"?